# Is there any package to show highlighted vector maps in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to implement a map like this:-
[image]

in which vector layers of countries are highlighted according to some metric value. I tried to search for some package but found JQuery based `JQVMaps` and `jvectormap`, which I want to avoid to use since my framework is VueJS.

Can someone suggest some package for this? Or should I go for integrating these Jquery based packages itself?

Comment: Currently I am looking for one, but without success, I have found this http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/ it is not vuejs but at least it is not jquery, it is pure javascript, maybe when I have some free time I will start to build one in vue based on this, I think it would be worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) is great and simple to learn library to work with maps. Fortunately there is a wrapper called [vue2-leaflet](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.com/) that make it work with Vue. Regarding your Image this [part](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/) of docs may useful for you.